# Как настроить валидацию на yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Дело в том, что у меня есть чекбокс, который отключает поле ввода, но несмотря на это, поля продолжает проверяется на валдиацию. Как правильно прописать правило, чтобы в момент,когда чекбокс не нажат проверка поля не производилась?

Comment: `продолжает проверяется на валдиацию` - по какому действию поля валидируются?

Comment: Вы можете вернуть `false` на событие [beforeValidate](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js#L39)

Comment: @zakiroof а могли бы вы показать пример как это должно выглядеть ?

Comment: Вообще-то вопрос немного некорректен. Валидация может происходить как на клиенте (`javascript`), так и на сервере (`php`). Где именно она Вам нужна?

Comment: Нужны примеры кода. Вью и модель.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно почитать про валидацию моделей в `Yii2` - `required when` и `required whenClient`

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/input-validation

В Вашем случае думаю будет выглядеть как-то так

```php
public function rules()
{
        return [
            [
                ['goodscount' ], 'required', 'message' => AdminModule::t('goods', 'Fill the field goodscount'),
                'when' => function( $model ) {
                    return ( !is_null( $model->buy_goods) && $model->buy_goods == 1 ); //проверка на стороне сервера
                },
                'whenClient' => 'function(attribute,value) {
                    return ( $("#basketform-buy_goods").is(':checked') ); //проверка на стороне браузера
                }'

            ],
         ]
}
```